# Difference between Administrator and WSS_Admin_WPG

Tags: permissions, powershell, central-administration, iis, sharepoint-server

What is difference between **Administrator** and  **WSS_Admin_WPG**, on the SharePoint Server Machine

1. Is Administrator rights on Server Machine enough to do all
   activities on SharePoint server , Power Shell and IIS Application
   pool
2. To perform any IIS and Power shell related activity is it necessary that user must belong to **IIS_IUSRS** and **SharePoint_Shell_Access** Group

Comment: I recommend you to read the first paragraphs in this Technet article as a starting point http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc678863.aspx

Answer (score 1):

1. "**Administrators**" Group will have full privilege in the system.
2. "**WSS_Admin_WPG**"  is used for Application Pool Accounts for Central Administration and Timer Services, they have very specific privileges in the system and they are as follows,

A. Rights to registry entries and

> "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\APPID{58F1D482-A132-4297-9B8A-F8E4E600CDF6} "
>   "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\APPID{6002D29F-1366-4523-88C1-56D59BFEF8CB} "
>   "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\VSS "
>   "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Registration{90120000-110D-0000-0000-0000000FF1CE}
>   " "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office Server "
>   "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office Server\14.0 "
>   "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Office
>   Server\14.0\LoadBalancerSettings "
>   "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Office
>   Server\14.0\LauncherSettings "
>   "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Office Server\14.0\Search "
>   "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Shared Tools\Web Server
>   Extensions\14.0\Search " "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Shared
>   Tools\Web Server Extensions\14.0\Secure "
>   "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Shared Tools\Web Server
>   Extensions\14.0\WSS "

B. Rights to file systems.

> "%AllUsersProfile%\Application Data\Microsoft\Sharepoint "
>   "C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\wss " "%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft Office
>   Servers\14.0 " "%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft Office
>   Servers\14.0\WebServices " "%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft Office
>   Servers\14.0\Data " "%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft Office Servers\14.0\Logs
>   " "%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft Office Servers\14.0\Data\Office Server "
>   "%windir%\System32\drivers\etc\HOSTS " "%windir%\Tasks "
>   "%COMMONPROGRAMFILES%Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14 "
>   "%COMMONPROGRAMFILES%\Microsoft Shared\Web Server
>   Extensions\14\ADMISAPI " "%COMMONPROGRAMFILES%\Microsoft Shared\Web
>   Server Extensions\14\CONFIG " "%COMMONPROGRAMFILES%\Microsoft
>   Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\LOGS " "%COMMONPROGRAMFILES%\Microsoft
>   Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\Data " "%windir%\temp "
>   "%windir%\System32\logfiles\SharePoint " "%systemdrive\program
>   files\Microsoft Office Servers\14 folder on Index servers "

Reference:

a.  http://sharepoint-community.net/forum/topics/difference-between-administrator-and-wss-admin-wpg

b. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc678863.aspx

c. [What are the relationship between administrators groups of domain, dev computer and of Sharepoint services?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/37740/what-are-the-relationship-between-administrators-groups-of-domain-dev-computer)